# $\lim\limits_{u\rightarrow\infty}|F_1(u,x)-F_2(u,x)|=0,\forall x\geq0\implies\lim\limits_{u\rightarrow\infty}\sup_{x\geq0}|F_1(u,x)-F_2(u,x)|=0$?

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, compactness

$\lim\limits_{u\rightarrow \infty}|F_1(u,x)-F_2(u,x)|=0,\forall x\geq 0  \ \implies \ \lim\limits_{u\rightarrow \infty}\sup\limits_{x\geq 0}|F_1(u,x)-F_2(u,x)|=0$ ?

I get the question when I read the proof of Theorem 7 from a paper titled *Statistical Inference Using Extreme Order Statistics* （link: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1176343003 ）

Is the statement above always true? If it is not always true, why it is true in the paper's case?

Answer (score 0):

No, take
\begin{align*}
F_1(u,x) = \frac{(x+1)^2}{u}, \quad F_2(u,x) = \frac{x^2}{u}
\end{align*}
Clearly,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{u\rightarrow \infty}|F_1(u,x) - F_2(u,x)| = \lim_{u\rightarrow \infty}\frac{2x + 1}{u} = 0
\end{align*}
for all $x \ge 0$. But
\begin{align*}
\lim_{u\rightarrow \infty}\sup_{x\ge 0}\frac{2x + 1}{u} = \infty
\end{align*}
You would need $F_1, F_2$ to both be uniformly continuous in $x$.

Comment: How to show if $F_1,F_2$ are uniformly continuous in $x$, then the statement hold?